# Java Path.startswith() broken?

Tags: java

I have to be misunderstanding [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#startsWith-java.nio.file.Path-).
Given the following code, I expect a "they match" printout. I get "oops. no match."

```
          Path p = Paths.get("C:\\fakename");
          Path q = Paths.get("C:\\fake");
          if(p.startsWith(q))
          {
             System.out.println("they match");   
          }
          else
          {
              System.out.println("oops. no match.");
          }
```

What am I misunderstanding? The documentation seems pretty clear.

Comment: For all you folks like me out there who read "element" and think "string", don't. It's talking about the actual path element. Oops. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What am I misunderstanding?

Well, the documentation states this:

> This path starts with the given path if this path's root component starts with the root component of the given path, **and this path starts with the same name elements as the given path**

And `fake` isn't the same name element as `fakename`!

Comment: Oh. Duh. I was doing string comparisons in my head. Thanks all!

Answer (score 5):

`Path` comparison is not `String` comparison.

`String.startsWith` take a single `String` argument representing any `String` contained within your target at its beginning.

`Path.startsWith(String other)`...

> Tests if this path starts with a Path, constructed by converting the given path string, in exactly the manner specified by the startsWith(Path) method. On UNIX for example, the path "foo/bar" starts with "foo" and "foo/bar". It does not start with "f" or "fo".

(quoted from [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#startsWith-java.nio.file.Path-)).

Comment: which would mean that `Path.get("C:\\dirA\\dirB").startsWith("C:\\dirA") == true` correct? (for clarification)

Comment: @sircapsalot Yes, that is accurate. I've tested it.

Comment: @sircapsalot sorry was afk. What kmort says.

Answer (score 2):

p and q are from Type "Path". If you want to use startsWith() you need the type "String".

so try this:

package newTestPackage.Contains;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class testwise {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path p = Paths.get("C:\\fakename");
    Path q = Paths.get("C:\\fake");

    if(p.toString().startsWith(q.toString()))
    {
       System.out.println("they match");   
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("oops. no match.");
    }
}
```

}

It`s my first answer here. I hope I was able to help you. :-)

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought it was doing in my head. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you linked :

```
 the path "foo/bar" starts with "foo" and "foo/bar". It does not start with "f" or "fo".
```

Answer (score 1):

But not clear enough, apparently.

Path comparisons check at the path *element* level, not the *string* level.

Comment: New to java. Still think in C. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It won't perform a `startsWith` on the folder name too. They don't start with the same path, hence the `false`.